# What is an example of an algorithm which uses Huffman coding only?

Tags: algorithm, encoding, compression, theory, huffman-code

For example, a LZM algorithm example could be the LZMA, but the Huffman example I can't find. I understand that BWT uses it to some extent, but it uses another type of algorithm too.

Comment: Surely *Huffman coding* **is** an algorithm itself ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I thought so too. However I cannot seem to find a compression algorithm which uses it solely (similar as the BWT)

Comment: @Samuelf80 With Huffman coding only you cannot go further when you face non ascii chars, that is why fast LZ algorithms skip this part, gzip uses for only sliding window part, for example if window size is 8K, then it uses huffman coding only for that window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean implementation, not algorithm. Huffman coding *is* an algorithm.

zlib provides the `Z_HUFFMAN_ONLY` compression strategy, which only uses Huffman coding to compress the input. The string matching zlib normally uses is turned off with that option.